# Form array of equivalence related classes

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, cell-array, equivalence-classes

I have an array in Matlab. I numbered every entry in array with natural number. So I formed equivalence relation in array.

For example,

```
array   = [1 2 3 5 6 7]
classes = [1 2 1 1 3 3].
```

I want to get cell array: `i`-th cell array's position is connected with `i`-th entry of initial array and shows, which elements are in the one class with this entry. For the example above, I would get:

```
{[1 3 5], [2], [1 3 5], [1 3 5], [6 7], [6 7]}
```

It can be done easily with for-loop, but is there any other solution? It will be good if it works faster than `O(n^2)`, where `n` is the size of initial array.

`Edit.`
Problem will be solved, if I know the approach to split sorted array into cells with indeces of equal elements by `O(n)`.

```
array  = [1 1 1 2 3 3]
groups = {[1 2 3], [4], [5 6]}
```

Comment: For clarity, could you include example code for the "done easily with for-loop" you want to do better than? Also, is your goal here real-world performance, or algorithmic study? Because in Matlab, there's such a big difference between M-code level and vectorized operations, `O(n)` complexity sometimes doesn't matter as much as which particular operations you're calling and at what "layer" of Matlab.

Comment: BTW, you could write that result cell array more concisely as `{[1 3 5], [2], [1 3 5], [1 3 5], [6 7], [6 7]}`. I think it's more readable in this form.

Comment: @Andrew Janke , Excuse me, I hastened with complexity evaluation. The aim is the algorithm, that works faster than O(n^2) - when we traverse array for every entry and form it's own cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do this without for-loops entirely, but you can use a combination of `sort`, `diff`, and `find` to organize and partition the equivalence class identifiers. That'll give you a mostly vectorized solution, where the M-code level for-loop is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of classes, not the length of the whole input array. This should be pretty fast in practice.

Here's a rough example using some index munging. Be careful; there's probably an off-by-one edge case bug in there somewhere since I just banged this out.

```
function [eqVals,eqIx] = equivsets(a,x)
%EQUIVSETS Find indexes of equivalent values

[b,ix] = sort(x);
ixEdges = find(diff(b)); % identifies partitions between equiv classes
ix2 = [0 ixEdges numel(ix)];
eqVals = cell([1 numel(ix2)-1]);
eqIx = cell([1 numel(ix2)-1]);
% Map back to original input indexes and values
for i = 1:numel(ix2)-1
    eqIx{i} = ix((ix2(i)+1):ix2(i+1));
    eqVals{i} = a(eqIx{i}); 
end
```

I included the indexes in the output because they're often more useful than the values themselves. You'd call it like this.

```
% Get indexes of occurrences of each class
equivs = equivsets(array, classes)
% You can expand that to get equivalences for each input element
equivsByValue = equivs(classes)
```

It's a lot more efficient to build the lists for each class first and then expand them out to match the input indexes. Not only do you have to do the work just once, but when you use the `b = a(ix)` to expand a small cell array to a larger one, Matlab's copy-on-write optimization will end up reusing the memory for the underlying numeric mxArrays so you get a more compact representation in memory.

This transformation pops up a lot when working with `unique()` or databases. For decision support systems and data warehouse style things I've worked with, it happens all over the place. I wish it were built in to Matlab. (And maybe it's been added to one of the db or timeseries toolboxes in recent years; I'm a few versions behind.)

Realistically, if performance of this is critical for your code, you might also look at dropping down to Java or C MEX functions and implementing it there. But if your data sets are low cardinality - that is, have a small number of classes/distinct values, like `numel(unique(classes)) / numel(array)` tends to be less than 0.1 or so - the M-code implementation will probably be just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about complexity, but [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with cell output is useful for splitting up the array based on unique values of the classes:

```
data = sortrows([classes; array].',1) %' stable w.r.t. array
arrayPieces = accumarray(data(:,1),data(:,2)',[],@(x){x.'})
classElements = arrayPieces(classes).'
```

---

Regarding sorted array splitting into cells of indeces:

```
>> array  = [1 1 1 2 3 3]
>> arrayinds = accumarray(array',1:numel(array),[],@(x){x'})' %' transpose for rows
arrayinds = 
    [1x3 double]    [4]    [1x2 double]
>> arrayinds{:}
ans =
     1     2     3
ans =
     4
ans =
     5     6
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second question:

```
array  = [1 1 1 2 3 3]; %// example data
```

1. Use `diff` to find the end of each run of equal values, and from that build the groups:

   ```
   ind = [0 find(diff([array NaN])~=0)];
   groups = arrayfun(@(n) ind(n)+1:ind(n+1), 1:numel(ind)-1, 'uni', 0);
   ```
2. Same approach using `unique`:

   ```
   [~, ind] = unique(array);
   ind = [0 ind];
   groups = arrayfun(@(n) ind(n)+1:ind(n+1), 1:numel(ind)-1, 'uni', 0);
   ```

I haven't tested if the complexity is O(n), though.